# Using a VBA class to calculate the density of humid air at a given temperature and relative humidity

Tags: vba, class

I'm trying to use a class module to perform some calculations using a small number of inputs and then return the result of those calculations.

I've never used classes before and I'm getting a 'Compile Error' (Invalid Outside Procedure).

Here's the class module (CDensityHumidAir) code:

```
Private pSaturationPressureWaterVapour As Double
Private pEso As Double
Private pP As Double
Private pC0 As Double
Private pC1 As Double
Private pC2 As Double
Private pC3 As Double
Private pC4 As Double
Private pC5 As Double
Private pC6 As Double
Private pC7 As Double
Private pC8 As Double
Private pC9 As Double
Private pPartialPressureWaterVapour As Double
Private pPartialPressureDryAir As Double
Private pDensityHumidAir As Double
Private pAmbientAirTempCelsius As Double
Private pAmbientAirTempKelvin As Double
Private pRelativeHumidity As Double
Private pBarometricPressure_hPa As Double
Private pBarometricPressure_Pa As Double
Private pGasConstantWaterVapour As Double
Private pGasConstantDryAir As Double


Public Sub CalculateDensityHumidAir()

pAmbientAirTempCelsius = 15 'Input
pAmbientAirTempKelvin = 273.15 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pRelativeHumity = 0.5 'Input
pBarometricPressure_hPa = 1029 'Input
pBarometricPressure_Pa = pBarometricPressure_hPa * 100
pEso = 6.1078
pGasConstantWaterVapour = 461.495
pGasConstantDryAir = 287.05
pC0 = 0.99999683
pC1 = -0.90826951 * 10 ^ -2
pC2 = 0.78736169 * 10 ^ -4
pC3 = -0.61117958 * 10 ^ -6
pC4 = 0.43884187 * 10 ^ -8
pC5 = -0.29883885 * 10 ^ -10
pC6 = 0.21874425 * 10 ^ -12
pC7 = -0.17892321 * 10 ^ -14
pC8 = 0.11112018 * 10 ^ -16
pC9 = -0.30994571 * 10 ^ -19
pC0_T = pC0 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC1_T = pC1 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC2_T = pC2 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC3_T = pC3 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC4_T = pC4 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC5_T = pC5 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC6_T = pC6 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC7_T = pC7 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius
pC8_T = pC8 + pAmbientAirTempCelsius

pP = (pC0_T * (pC1_T * (pC2_T * (pC3_T * (pC4_T * (pC5_T * (pC6_T * (pC7_T * (pC8_T * (pC9))))))))))

pSaturationPressureWaterVapour = pEso / (pP ^ 8)

pPartialPressureWaterVapour = pRelativeHumidity * pSaturationPressureWaterVapour * 100

pPartialPressureDryAir = pBarometricPressure_Pa - pPartialPressureWaterVapour

pDensityHumidAir = pPartialPressureDryAir / (pGasConstantDryAir * pAmbientAirTempKelvin) + pPartialPressureWaterVapour / (pGasConstantWaterVapour * pAmbientAirTempKelvin)

End Sub

'AmbientAirTemperature Property
Public Property Get AmbientAirTemperature()
    AmbientAirTemperature = pAmbientAirTempCelsius
End Property
Public Property Let AmbientAirTempertaure(Value As Double)
    pAmbientAirTemperature = Value
End Property

'RelativeHumidity Property
Public Property Get RelativeHumidity()
    RelativeHumidity = pRelativeHumidity
End Property
Public Property Let RelativeHumidity(Value As Double)
    pRelativeHumidity = Value
End Property

'BarometricPressure Property
Public Property Get BarometricPressure()
    BarometricPressure = pBarometricPressure_hPa
End Property
Public Property Let BarometricPressure(Value As Double)
    pBarometricPressure_hPa = Value
End Property

'DensityHumidAir Property
Public Property Get DensityHumidAir()
    DensityHumidAir = pDensityHumidAir
End Property
```

This is the code in the module where I'm trying to set the input variables and print the result to the immediate window.

```
Dim DensityHumidAir As CDensityHumidAir
Set Tmp = New CDensityHumidAir
Tmp.AmbientAirTemperature = 15
Tmp.RelativeHumity = 0.5
Tmp.Barometric.Pressure = 1000
Debug.Print Tmp.DensityHumidAir
```

I've tried looking up the error message but it seems to suggest something hasn't been declared but I can tell what it is. To be frank, I'd be surprised if that was the only issue. I suspect once that's solved, I'll get some more error messages. What have I done wrong?

Comment: you need to set types for your get's like `Public Property Get BarometricPressure() As Double` and st defaults or validate inputs to

Comment: `pAmbientAirTemp` is not defined

Comment: Just a head up to answerers, this is also [cross-posted on Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/157633/36565).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click Tools => Options and enable *Require variable declaration* to make the IDE issue errors on undeclared variables.

Make all your `Get`s return the correct type:

```
Public Property Get DensityHumidAir() As Double
```

Fix the missing properties:

```
Tmp.RelativeHumity = 0.5
```

`RelativeHumity` does not exist in the class.

Fix your typos/logic glitches:

```
'AmbientAirTemperature Property
Public Property Get AmbientAirTemperature()
    AmbientAirTemperature = pAmbientAirTemp
End Property

Public Property Let AmbientAirTempertaure(Value As Double)
    pAmbientAirTemperature = Value
End Property
```

Here there is a typo (*Tempertaure*) so the properties have different names.
They also assign to different module variables, neither of which exist (should it be `pAmbientAirTempCelsius` which does?).

Comment: Thanks Alex K, when I run the script like this Tmp.DensityHumidAir = 0, but when I run the code inside its own module the answer comes out as 1.2... Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: If you get a result without a syntax error you are going to have to debug & step through each operation to check the logic/math is correct.